# Disable dropdown after page refresh in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to make 3 drop downs disabled in jquery after clicking on the Submit button. The submit button will refresh the page and stay in same page so I wasn't able put the code in Button click of submit as page get refreshed so I have in in document.ready.My code works in chrome but not working in IE8.

this is my jquery code:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  var Entity = $("#Entity").val()
  var LicenseType = $("#LicenseType").val();
 var State = $("#State").val();
 if (Entity.length > 0 && LicenseType.length > 0 && State.length > 0) {
    $("#Entity").attr('disabled', true).trigger("liszt:updated");
    $("#LicenseType").attr('disabled', true).trigger("liszt:updated");
    $("#State").attr('disabled', true).trigger("liszt:updated");
}
});
```

Comment: what jquery version are you using? + `var Entity = $("#Entity").val()` missing `;` at the end

Comment: Have you tried :   $("#Entity").prop('disabled', true) ?

Comment: try $('#Entity').prop('disabled', 'disabled'). Is it working in IE9+ ? I know depending on your environment you may have to support IE8, But just an FYI, as of Jan 12, 2016 Microsoft is dropping support for IE8. No more updates or security fixes.

Comment: @AndrewEvt oh my god that was it thanks!